# C++ passing a templated functor as a template typename

Tags: c++

I have a templated function:

```
template <typename my_func> int foo(int x, int y) {
 my_func bar;
 return bar(x, y);
}
```

which I can use with following functor:

```
struct _compare {
int operator()(int x, int y) { return x-y;  }
};
```

Usage: `foo<_compare>(int x, int y)`

In fact there is a tight loop in `foo` and thus i'm trying to pass pointer to functions that can be inlined at compile time.

Now I want to use a function from 3rd party lib, which is templated fuctor by itself. The new functor is like:

```
template<typename Scalar> struct _compare {
  Scalar operator()(const Scalar& a, const Scalar& b) const {
      return a-b;
  }
};
```

And I can't make it compile. I've tried `foo<_compare<char>>(int x, int y)`
I've tried

```
const char t = 0;
foo<_compare<t>>(int x, int y);
```

I've tried to `foo<_compare>(int x, int y)` and change `foo` to

```
template <typename my_func> foo(int x, int y) {
 my_func<char> bar;
 bar(x, y);
}
```

As I need only `_compare < char >` for sure.
Any hints?

Comment: Your `foo` seems to be missing return type.

Comment: please include a [mcve] and the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code perfectly compiles, but fails to compile if one changes the name of `_compare2` to `_compare`. Maybe this could have been your problem.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct _compare2 {
int operator()(int x, int y) { return x-y;  }
};

template <typename my_func>
int foo(int x, int y) {
 my_func bar;
 bar(x, y);
}

template<typename Scalar> struct _compare {
  Scalar operator()(const Scalar& a, const Scalar& b) const {
      return a-b;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** args) {
        std::cout << foo<_compare2>(4,2) << std::endl;
        std::cout << foo<_compare<int>>(4,2) << std::endl;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Good shot. I did provide an alternative answer, but responding to the exact request is good for future readers.

Comment: You're right. In real project I had 2 nested templated  functions `foo1` and `foo2` where `foo1` just checks some params and passes template args and args to `foo2`. They had equal argument name set. Indeed I was self confident and suggestion to provide a minimal reproducible example in comments would save me a time.

Answer (score 5):

My preferred solution would be to do like the STL does: always pass the function object as parameter:

```
template<typename my_func>
void foo(int x, int y, my_func bar) {
    bar(x, y);
}
```

Then, it doesn't matter if `my_func` is a templated class, a lambda, a non templated class or even a function pointer. It just work.

Usage:

```
foo(int x, int y, _compare{});
foo(int x, int y, _compare<char>{});
foo(int x, int y, [](int, int){ return false; });
```

This [Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/c8ZLC_) shows that C++ completely elide both callable, and the function call and its result.

Also, the GCC ABI has no storage for empty classes sent as parameter to a function, removing overhead if not inlined.

Comment: What about inlining such function. Will GCC be able to inline it?

Comment: @truf If a compiler is not able to inline something like this, I would report a bug. I'll edit with a live example

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a function pointer in the template

```
template <bool (*compare)(int, int)>
bool cmp(int i, int j)
{
    return compare(i, j);
}
```